# Python 7Zip Error Fails with Scan Warning

Tags: python, 7zip

I'm on my Mac with a small Python script to 7 zip and encrypt it. Here is my Python code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import zipfile
import sys

os.environ['ZIP_ENCRYPT_PASS'] = 'test'
password = os.environ['ZIP_ENCRYPT_PASS']

# Step 1: Encrypt the file using AES256
rc = subprocess.call(['/usr/local/Cellar/p7zip/16.02_1/bin/7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', password, '-y', 'myarchive.zip'] + 
                    ['/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/test.txt', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/some.txt'])
```

I have those 2 files in the specified folder that I want to 7zip and encrypt it with a password!

When I ran this program, I get the following:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:python-projects joe$ python ./test.py

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive:

WARNING: No more files
myarchive.zip

2 files, 245 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: test.7z

Items to compress: 2


Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

myarchive.zip : No more files
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1


System ERROR:
E_INVALIDARG
```

Why should this fail? I have two problems here:

1. There is no good support for 7zip in Python
2. There is no good support for 7zip on Mac

But I thought my code above should work as I was able to get rid of both the problems by installing the 7zip using homebrew on Mac. So I did:

```
brew install p7zip
```

I then gave the path to the 7z in my subprocess call. But still this fails! Any ideas on how to get it to work?

EDIT: I just checked what the arguments could be and here is what I get:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:bin joesan$ 7z --help

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive
  e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  h : Calculate hash values for files
  i : Show information about supported formats
  l : List contents of archive
  rn : Rename files in archive
  t : Test integrity of archive
  u : Update files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full paths

<Switches>
  -- : Stop switches parsing
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude archives
  -ao{a|s|t|u} : set Overwrite mode
  -an : disable archive_name field
  -bb[0-3] : set output log level
  -bd : disable progress indicator
  -bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line
  -bt : show execution time statistics
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include filenames
  -m{Parameters} : set compression Method
    -mmt[N] : set number of CPU threads
  -o{Directory} : set Output directory
  -p{Password} : set Password
  -r[-|0] : Recurse subdirectories
  -sa{a|e|s} : set Archive name mode
  -scc{UTF-8|WIN|DOS} : set charset for for console input/output
  -scs{UTF-8|UTF-16LE|UTF-16BE|WIN|DOS|{id}} : set charset for list files
  -scrc[CRC32|CRC64|SHA1|SHA256|*] : set hash function for x, e, h commands
  -sdel : delete files after compression
  -seml[.] : send archive by email
  -sfx[{name}] : Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}] : read data from stdin
  -slp : set Large Pages mode
  -slt : show technical information for l (List) command
  -snh : store hard links as links
  -snl : store symbolic links as links
  -sni : store NT security information
  -sns[-] : store NTFS alternate streams
  -so : write data to stdout
  -spd : disable wildcard matching for file names
  -spe : eliminate duplication of root folder for extract command
  -spf : use fully qualified file paths
  -ssc[-] : set sensitive case mode
  -ssw : compress shared files
  -stl : set archive timestamp from the most recently modified file
  -stm{HexMask} : set CPU thread affinity mask (hexadecimal number)
  -stx{Type} : exclude archive type
  -t{Type} : Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName] : Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g] : Create volumes
  -w[{path}] : assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude filenames
  -y : assume Yes on all queries
```

How can I now pass this as argument to by subprocess so that my Python code works?

Comment: It says `invalid argument`

Comment: It does not say which argument is invalid! It is not so intuitve! Have you got an idea which argument is invalid? It would help!

Comment: Could you give me the full commandline for th `7z` with arguments?

Comment: `7z a -tzip DestinyTest.zip destiny1.txt destiny4.txt destiny6.txt` this is the usage, i think. Are you sure, you have the right usage ?

Comment: What about the password and the encryption?

Comment: `7z a -tzip -mem=AES256 -p"PASSWORD" allfiles.zip fileone filetwo filethree`. Looks like you don't have the `password` argument

Comment: Please make sure it runs manually before trying it using scripts

Comment: It does work, but when I tried to run it from the Python code, it works as well, but it creates a test.zip instead of myarchive.zip as I want it to be!

Comment: zip works, but now unzip fails and it complains of Bad Password! This is really strange and I'm wondering how people work with such a language like Python!

Comment: Use this `['/usr/local/Cellar/p7zip/16.02_1/bin/7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', '-p', password, '-y', '-tzip', 'myarchive.zip', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/test.txt', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/some.txt']`

Comment: This is not the `python` issue. This never was a `python` issue. You just didn't use the call correctly

Comment: What you gave as an option to use does not work! It creates a test.zip file and it would ask for a password! This is indeed the problem with the way Python expects arguments!

Comment: As i have mentioned, i do not know much about the usage of `7z`. Please see the usage and use it in the call correctly

Comment: I have tested this. `7z a -mem=AES256 -pmy_password -tzip foo.zip foo bar` too zip and the `7z x  foo.zip -pmy_password` to unzip. It works fine

Comment: Working from the command line does not mean that it works with Python. Try it in the Python code and you will notice that it fails!

Comment: Please see my answer. I did it interactively, since you specifically asked for it :)

Comment: Yes, I managed to get it zipped, but strangely unzipping fails! Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265643/unable-to-extract-encrypted-zip-file-in-python and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the correct `7z` arguments,

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
└── foo

0 directories, 2 files
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> zip_cmd = '7z a -mem=AES256 -pmy_password -tzip foo.zip foo bar'
>>> passwd = 'my_password'
>>> zip_cmd = ['/usr/bin/7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', '-p{}'.format(passwd), '-tzip', 'foo.zip', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> zip_cmd
['/usr/bin/7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', '-pmy_password', '-tzip', 'foo.zip', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> subprocess.call(zip_cmd)

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_IN.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (206A7),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
2 files, 27 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: foo.zip

Items to compress: 2


Files read from disk: 2
Archive size: 385 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok
0
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
['bar', 'foo', 'foo.zip']
>>>
>>> os.mkdir('test')
>>> os.listdir('.')
['bar', 'test', 'foo', 'foo.zip']
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copy('foo.zip', 'test')
>>> os.chdir('test')
>>> os.listdir('.')
['foo.zip']
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/telaverge/python/purge/test'
>>> unzip_cmd = ['/usr/bin/7z', 'x', 'foo.zip', '-p{}'.format(passwd)]
>>> unzip_cmd
['/usr/bin/7z', 'x', 'foo.zip', '-pmy_password']
>>> subprocess.call(unzip_cmd)

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_IN.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (206A7),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 385 bytes (1 KiB)

Extracting archive: foo.zip
--
Path = foo.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 385

Everything is Ok

Files: 2
Size:       27
Compressed: 385
0
>>> os.listdir('.')
['bar', 'foo', 'foo.zip']
```