# Unable to Extract Encrypted Zip File in Python

Tags: python, zip

I'm not able to extract a password protected zip file using Python. Here is the snippet that I use:

```
import os
import subprocess
import zipfile
import sys

# Step 1: Encrypt the file using AES256
rc = subprocess.call(['/usr/local/Cellar/p7zip/16.02_1/bin/7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', '-pP4$$W0rd', '-y', 'myarchive.zip'] + 
                    ['/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/aaa.txt', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/bbb.txt'])

# Step 2: Decrypt the archive
f = zipfile.ZipFile('myarchive.zip').extractall(pwd='P4$$W0rd')
```

Here is the error message. As it can be seen that I can successfully encrypt and zip the file using a password, but when I tried to extract it using the same password, it fails! Very strange!

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:python-projects joe$ python ./test.py

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive:
2 files, 245 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: myarchive.zip

Items to compress: 2


Files read from disk: 2
Archive size: 534 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    f = zipfile.ZipFile('myarchive.zip').extractall(pwd='P4$$W0rd')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1040, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1028, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1082, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1007, in open
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x106354438>)
Joes-MacBook-Pro:python-projects joe$
```

Why is this? Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue9170. This is an issue with the AES encryption

Comment: So, looks like better to use `7z` to unzip as well ?

Comment: Is there some API documentation on doing this? Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this!

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/local/Cellar/p7zip/16.02_1/bin/7z", "x", '-p{}'.format(passwd), "myarchive.zip"])
```

Seems like there is a bug with AES encryption and Python ZipFile!

Comment: This is not *Python* per se, it's *shell* commands wrapped in *Python* (wonder why the trouble). A *Python* solution would be to use *PKWARE* passwords but it has some limitations as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532010/zipfile-badzipfile-bad-crc-32-when-extracting-a-password-protected-zip-zip/55063500#55063500

Comment: Yes, it is indeed, but it just works for me! I need AES256 encryption and this way of doing it seems to be the only possibility, given the known bug in Python ZipFile which is not compatible with AES256 encrypted passwords!

Answer (score -2):

this may work.

```
f = zipfile.ZipFile('myarchive.zip').extractall(pwd=bytes(‘P4$$W0rd‘,'utf-8'))
```

Comment: It would not. Since 'foo' and bytes('foo', 'utf-8') are not the  same. And that is not even the problem, to start with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is what i saw in the documentation for zipfile